# Windows Phone 8 Web Post return boolean AFTER call back completed?

Tags: c#, webclient, windows-phone

I'm trying to make an application in windows phone 8 and make it easy to extend or change by coding it in to simple classes. I would like to do a simple web call with a webclient that does a HTTP POST to log a user in to a service. Here is the flow I have so far:

- User enters username and api details or they are called from previously saved details.
- WebClient does a POST to web service and receives XML response with user information etc.
- Call back executes after having set `WebClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(name)`
- User information is processed and stuff done with it.

For various reasons and mainly for wanting to code in to classes and ultimately release the code as a free SDK for other developers, I wish the flow to look like this:

- User enters details or called from saved details.
- Function within class called something similar to `if(class.Authenticate(user,apikey)){logged in stuff};` which returns a `boolean` value or even better an integer value so I can easily process errors from the web service.

Nothing i have tried will make this work and I can't get my head around how to make it work with async and await as webclients just seem to execute on their own thread and wouldn't hold one up for me until the call back was completed.

I've found a custom webclient class somewhere but it only did GET requests which isn't good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do this.

To do this you would need to block the executing thread until the server responds:
- This could be a very long time.
- If on the UI thread this would stop the user interacting with the UI.
- What if there's no, or a very slow, connection

This is the reason that `WebClient` doesn't have a synchronous way of making calls.

There are ways to make the execution appear synchronous but you'll get a lot more from learning to work with the framework and understanding why it wants you to work a specific way and why that's appropriate on an occasionally connected device.

You could also make this code look synchronous by making an Awaitable request. See more at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx

Comment: no really, I do want to do this. I want to build it in to a simple class that others can use.